# How to update two tables in a single query in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Is it be possible to update two tables writing a single query?

So that i do not have to execute two queries and to track whether both are successful?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it in a query but you can do it as a transaction when all queries within the transaction will either succeed or fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a stored procedure that updates the two tables and returns whatever you need it to in order to determine success. This stored proc can then be called from a single command. However, it will still have to contain two queries.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible AFAIK.

EDIT: What is the **reason** for you to achieve this in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction), however you are still required to update the tables separately and check the results before committing or rolling back.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can by using [triggers](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i)